EMR Cluster using boto3 - Service Role Insufficient Permissions
I am trying to create an EMR Cluster in AWS. It works well and the cluster is created when I do it through UI.
It is also working well when I create it using command line using the following command:
aws emr create-cluster \
 --name "emr-cluster" \
 --log-uri "s3n://aws-logs-433212232334-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/" \
 --release-label "emr-7.1.0" \
 --service-role "arn:aws:iam::433212232334:role/service-role/AmazonEMR-ServiceRole-20240418T133040" \
 --ec2-attributes '{"InstanceProfile":"AmazonEMR-InstanceProfile-20240418T133024","EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup":"sg-07ced3d3223bet564","EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup":"sg-04b7742eed31ec137","KeyName":"emr-key-pair","AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups":[],"AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups":[],"SubnetId":"subnet-0cf42a674f981a42a"}' \
 --tags 'for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies=true' \
 --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Spark \
 --configurations '[{"Classification":"spark-hive-site","Properties":{"hive.metastore.client.factory.class":"com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"}}]' \
 --instance-groups '[{"InstanceCount":1,"InstanceGroupType":"CORE","Name":"Core","InstanceType":"m5.xlarge","EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"VolumeType":"gp2","SizeInGB":32},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]}},{"InstanceCount":1,"InstanceGroupType":"MASTER","Name":"Primary","InstanceType":"m5.xlarge","EbsConfiguration":{"EbsBlockDeviceConfigs":[{"VolumeSpecification":{"VolumeType":"gp2","SizeInGB":32},"VolumesPerInstance":2}]}}]' \
 --scale-down-behavior "TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION" \
 --auto-termination-policy '{"IdleTimeout":3600}' \
 --region "us-east-1"

But when I run it using boto3, cluster is terminating with following error:
Service role arn:aws:iam::433212232334:role/service-role/AmazonEMR-ServiceRole-20240418T133040 has insufficient EC2 permissions
Here is the boto3 code:
import boto3

emr_client = boto3.client('emr')
response = emr_client.run_job_flow(
    Name='emr-cluster',
    LogUri='s3n://aws-logs-433212232334-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/',
    ReleaseLabel='emr-7.1.0',
    ServiceRole="arn:aws:iam::433212232334:role/service-role/AmazonEMR-ServiceRole-20240418T133040",
    JobFlowRole="AmazonEMR-InstanceProfile-20240418T133024",
    ScaleDownBehavior='TERMINATE_AT_TASK_COMPLETION',
    EbsRootVolumeSize=15,
    AutoTerminationPolicy={
        'IdleTimeout': 3600
    },
    Applications=[
        {
            'Name': 'Spark'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Hadoop'
        }
    ],

    Configurations=[
        {
            "Classification": "spark-hive-site",
            "Properties": {
                "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
            }
        }
    ],
    Instances={
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'Ec2KeyName': 'emr-key-pair',
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "InstanceRole": "CORE",
                "Name": "Core",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "EbsConfiguration": {
                    "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                        {
                            "VolumeSpecification": {
                                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                                "SizeInGB": 32
                            },
                            "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "InstanceCount": 1,
                "InstanceRole": "MASTER",
                "Name": "Primary",
                "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge",
                "EbsConfiguration": {
                    "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                        {
                            "VolumeSpecification": {
                                "VolumeType": "gp2",
                                "SizeInGB": 32
                            },
                            "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }

)

Why is it that when I use the same service role while creating cluster using AWS Web Console or AWS CLI, it works well, but when I do the same using boto3, the cluster is throwing this error that the service role does not have enough permissions?

To resolve the permission error when creating an EMR cluster using Boto3:

Use the AmazonElasticMapReduceRole policy for the EMR service role.
Ensure the service role has
a trust relationship allowing elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com to
assume the role.

For the instance profile:

Apply the AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role policy.
Configure the instance profile with a trust relationship that permits ec2.amazonaws.com to assume the role.

By setting up these roles with the correct policies and trust relationships, you should avoid the "insufficient EC2 permissions" error.
